# Unprotect the sheet, Protect some cells and leave the other ones free

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following code:

```
Sub UnProtect4User()
Dim ws As Workbook

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook

Worksheets("Datos").Unprotect Password:="2020"
MsgBox "The Sheet is unprotected"

ws.Sheets("Datos").Range("A2:J350").Locked = False

ws.Sheets("Datos").Protect Password:="2020"

MsgBox "Now you can edit"

End Sub
```

When the workbook opens, all the sheet is protected. If i press a button, the code on top would run to lock the cells which have formulas on it so the user cant touch them and let them change the other ones which are free. 
The problem is that when the last row activates, it protects again all the sheet.

Here is the file: [Data File](http://www.mediafire.com/file/1s4oygb090t0000/Datos.xlsm/file)

Comment: Which is the range with formulas?

Comment: @TimWilliams From M:2 to N:350 but i want to include K:2  to L:350 too because its data stored from logged users, so i don´t want any to change that.

Comment: Cells which are unlocked should not be protected once you re-protect the sheet.  Similar code is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried it several times, and all cells are currently locked, which seemed weird do to the fact that I'm stating not to lock those range of cells.

Comment: What happens if you add `Debug.Print ws.Sheets("Datos").Range("A2").Locked` just before the `End Sub` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams i added it and remains the same, with no changes. Thought a msgbox would appear, but no

Comment: It should output to the Immediate pane in the VB editor window. You may need to show that window (Ctrl+G) if it's not already open.  Or switch to use a MsgBox if you prefer.

Comment: @TimWilliams It says False on the new window

Comment: Then your code should work fine, unless there's some other code somewhere which is re-locking those cells.

Comment: @TimWilliams i do not, i have the following code to protect the worksheet when it opens: `Worksheets("Datos").Protect Password:="2020", Contents:=True, _
        AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
        AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
       AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True`
And the other code, it's assigned to a button to do it manually when clicked.

Comment: Can you share the workbook ? (you can delete any sheet content, just leaving the relevant code)

Comment: @TimWilliams sure, i will add it now then.

Comment: You need to allow the "Select unlocked cells" option when protecting the sheet...

Answer (score 0):

If you uncheck the option for "Select unlocked cells" in the "Protect sheet" dialog, then even unlocked cells can't be edited, because the user is prevented from selecting them.

Comment: I found a way to do it manually but can´t find which code triggers that option

Comment: You must have set it at some point and it just persisted.  see here for how to do that via VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enableselection

Comment: Excelent, now i got it working. One more question, is there a way to revert the selection, so when the excel opens, all the workbook is protected as it did before?

Comment: Yes - in the workbook_open sub you'd unprotect the sheet, lock all the cells, then re-protect the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In `ThisWorkbook` this is the new code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Workbook

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook

ClearFilters

Worksheets("Datos").Unprotect Password:="2020"

With Worksheets("Datos")
.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

ws.Sheets("Datos").Range("A2:N350").Locked = True
End With

Worksheets("Datos").Protect Password:="2020", Contents:=True, _
        AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
        AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
       AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub
```

And in the module:

```
Dim ws As Workbook

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook

Worksheets("Datos").Unprotect Password:="2020"

With Worksheets("Datos")
.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

ws.Sheets("Datos").Range("A2:L350").Locked = False

ws.Sheets("Datos").Protect Password:="2020"

End With

MsgBox "It's now unprotected, so you can work on it buddy."

End Sub
```

It's all working as its intended, so thank you Tim Williams for the help